# focus pointer in center radio button with css3

Tags: css, radio-button

I've customized this radio button and have trouble focusing the pointer inside the radio button .

```
<div class="radio">
    <input id="left" type="radio" name="gender" value="left">
    <label for="left">Left</label>
    <input id="right" type="radio" name="gender" value="right">
    <label for="right">Right</label>
</div>

label {

    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

input[type=radio] {

    display: none;
}

label:before {

    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-color: #bababa;
}

.radio label:before {

    border-radius: 8px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {

    content: "\2022";
    color: #373c3e;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

Deputy example so that you can see the error.

Visit https://jsfiddle.net/drag/rbhzpvn3/1/

Comment: how about this https://jsfiddle.net/1wu5o2x3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set just background color instead of > content: "\2022".

it means :

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {

background-color: #373c3e;
```

}